# What license(s) are the Tor Browser Bundles licensed under?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, legal

When I go to download the Tor Browser Bundle, I cannot find any license information about the licenses that are applicable to the Tor Browser Bundle either included as a LICENSE file in the download, nor on the download page of the website (the usual places I check for licenses).

I'm aware that Tor is Open Source, but I cannot find out which specific license(s) the Tor Browser Bundle as a whole is licensed under - including core Tor, Vidalia, Tor Button, Tor Browser etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser itself is a customised version of Mozilla Firefox Aurora, so the license in that case comes from Mozilla.  Many of the components have their own licenses, but essentially you're looking at the GPL, various iterations of the BSD/MIT license, the OpenSSL license and some Tor specific stuff.

There is more detail in the [Tor FAQ](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#DistributingTor) and it doesn't count the trademark for the Tor name and logo.